# array_splice not replacing array key value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to replace the value of the array key `type` when a checkbox has been selected in my html form.

```
$trip['subtrips'] = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count($trip['locations'])-1; $i++) {
    array_push($trip['subtrips'], ['type' => 'normal', 'start' => $trip['locations'][$i], 'end' => $trip['locations'][$i+1]]);
}

if(isset($trip['standard'])) {
  array_splice($trip['subtrips'], 0, 0, ['type' => 'standard']);
}
```

The code above is resulting in the array below which is wrong.

```
Array ( 

[0] => standard 

 [1] => Array ( 
   [type] => normal 
   [start] => Location 1
   [end] => Location 2

) )
```

The array below is the desired output i want to get

```
Array ( 

  [0] => Array ( 
    [type] => standard 
    [start] => Location 1
    [end] => Location 2

) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Issue by determining what type needs to be assigned to a trip inside of the for loop (like greeflas said) instead of making a completely new for loop

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($trip['locations'])-1; $i++) {
     array_push($trip['subtrips'], ['type' => isset($trip['standard']) ? 'standard' : 'normal', 'start' => $trip['locations'][$i], 'end' => $trip['locations'][$i+1]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `array_splice()` function here. You can determine type in for loop before pushing new item to array.